# how can i use grep to find IPV4 Number in a pcap file with regx syntac?

Tags: grep, ip, regex

I'm new in ubuntu.

I have this IP regex `'\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b'`
I have a network pcap file, I want to use this regex and the grep -e to find all IP address in the file.

I tried: `egrep '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}' -f Ncapture.pcap`

How can I use the grep command to find IP in a network pcap file?

Comment: Can you please post a small sample part of the pcap file?

Comment: sure here a sample:/Downloads$ tcpdump -tttt -r Ncapture.pcap
reading from file Ncapture.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
2013-01-12 18:37:42.871346 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.12 tell 192.168.0.1, length 46
2013-01-12 18:38:02.227995 IP 192.168.0.1.1901 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 300
2013-01-12 18:38:02.231699 IP 192.168.0.1.1901 >

Comment: Please edit your question with the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `egrep` command is working for me, to make the `grep -e` work just escape the control characters, and to make it print only the IP-s use the `-o` option for grep:

```
tcpdump -nr Ncapture.pcap | grep -oe '\(\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\)\(\.\|$\)\)\{4\}'
```

But as I see this will print a dot at the end of the IP, if you don't like that, then you have to add the last octet separatly, i.e:

```
tcpdump -nr Ncapture.pcap | grep -oe '\(\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\)\(\.\|$\)\)\{3\}\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\)'
```

To make it only print an IP once:

```
tcpdump -nr Ncapture.pcap | grep -oe '\(\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\)\(\.\|$\)\)\{3\}\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\)' | sort | uniq
```