# grep string from a pcap file

Tags: grep

I'm trying to figure out the correct command syntax. I have a pcap file, and I want to use grep, and grep only to take out all of the uniq ip addresses from without the file

So assuming the file is called capture.pcap and is in my home folder, what should I write?

I assume the regex can be `'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'`
and that `sort` and `uniq` must be included also, but it seems the pcap doesn't respond well with grep, for example using the normal syntax of grep file word doesn't work, if I run: `grep 239 ./capture.pcap` I get the replay `Binary file ./capture/pcap matches`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `-a` or `--binary-file=text` options

```
grep -aE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file.pcap
```

or

```
grep --binary-file=text -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file.pcap
```

This appears to work for a random pcap file that I downloaded from wiki.wireshark.org i.e.

```
$ grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' NTLM-wenchao.pcap
Binary file NTLM-wenchao.pcap matches
```

but

```
$ grep -aE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' NTLM-wenchao.pcap
Host: 192.168.0.55
Host: 192.168.0.55
Host: 192.168.0.55
Location: http://192.168.0.55/default.aspx
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6421
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://192.168.0."_?"_Ea@yÀ¨[À¨ÃPþµû%RÑ_Pü>ÕGET /default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.55
```

etc.

Be aware of the warning (from the man page `man grep`) that

```
If TYPE is text, grep processes a binary file as if  it
were  text;  this is equivalent to the -a option.  Warning: grep
--binary-files=text might output binary garbage, which can  have
nasty  side  effects  if  the  output  is  a terminal and if the
terminal driver interprets some of it as commands.
```

Note that although you can use the `\d` regex (for **d**igit), it is only supported by grep in PCRE mode (i.e. with the `-P` switch).

Comment: That is only going to pull plain text strings out of it, which in your case happens to include some http requests that contain plain text IP addresses.

Comment: well actually, amazingly, that works! id rate you up but im not 15 reputation yet! - also for some reason i cant seem to sort this to only show each address once.. i thought i need to use | uniq but that doesnt work for me..

Comment: Look at the `-o` flag for grep and `sort -u` instead of `uniq` (which only works on pre-sorted data). Also please see the comment from @psusi - I don't work with pcap files, so I don't know if this really does what you need, I just added it to illustrate generically how to get grep to work with binary files.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` works on text, the .pcap file is a binary file, which means *using grep only* you can't do what you want. [The .pcap file format](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) With *using grep only* you could only find those IP-s in the .pcap file, which are in the packet data section. (e.g. the capture file contains the packets of a webpage download, where the webpage is about IP-s) So to be short, *using grep only* you can't do that.

But why do you have to use only grep? Is this some kind of homework? (I answered a [very similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/389692/221281) 3 days ago.

Comment: yes exactly its a homework assignment! so according to your other answer, shouldnt grep -e solve the issue for me entirely? even tho the file is binary? im having trouble believing its impossible because if it is ill have to kill my teacher.

Comment: How would `grep -e` change anything? It still only searches for text. I can't imagine how would it be possible. I will be amazed if your teacher does present a solution for this. But anyway, homework is off-topic here.

Comment: well it doesn't have to be regarded as homework, its just a way to know alternative methods to do something. many things can be done in many diff ways in ubuntu - that being "homework" is an excuse to learn many methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `strings` command, with `grep` ?

e.g:

your pcap file: abc.pcap

```
strings abc.pcap | grep "Your Search String Goes Here"
```

Comment: The IP addresses in .pcap file are not in string format, they are in native binary format (just 4 bytes). To decode a .pcap file, `tcpdump` should be used, and then one can `grep` the output of `tcpdump`.

Comment: Yeah,  You're right I agree